# algorithmicx, broken left align with custom numbering

Tags: horizontal-alignment, numbering, algorithmicx

I am trying to use the algorithmic package with Step1. Step2. instead of 1, 2, ... line numbering and I have numberless lines. An example:

```
\documentclass[11 pt]{report}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{My Algorithm}
\algrenewcommand{\alglinenumber}[1]{\bf Step{#1}.}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State aaa
\Statex bbb
\State ccc
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

However, aaa bbb and ccc are not properly left aligned. How can I fix it?

Edit: I have edited the code to make it compilable (MWE)

Answer (score 1):

You should also redefine `\Statex` to take into account the width:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{My Algorithm}
\algrenewcommand{\alglinenumber}[1]{\bfseries Step {#1}.}
\renewcommand{\Statex}{\item[\hphantom{\bfseries Step \arabic{ALG@line}.}]}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State aaa
\Statex bbb
\State ccc
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

This will align the item with the preceding one.

[image]

Note that the size option must be written `11pt` and not `11 pt`; moreover `\bf` is an obsolete command and `\bfseries` should be used in its place.